# What is the uniform structure on a topological vector space?

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, uniform-spaces

I've read that topological vector spaces are canonically [uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space), however the definitions of uniform space are quite cryptic to me! Is there a simple/intuitive way to understand why we have good notions of Cauchy sequence/uniform convergence/uniform continuity on topological vector spaces?

Answer (score 4):

The standard way (AFAIK) to do this, is to take a local base of neighbourhoods $\mathscr{B}$ for $0$ in the TVS $X$. Then define the uniformity $\mathscr{U}$ generated by all entourages $B^\ast := \{(x,y) \in X^2: y-x \in B\}$ for every element $B$ from the local base, and showing it is family is a base for a uniformity compatible with the topology on $X$. This should be proved in any decent text on TVS's I think.

Comment: I never studied topological vector spaces, but isn't a TVS a topological group under vector addition? So wouldn't the uniform structure on the TVS just the uniform structure on that topological group?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Note that this answer contains no scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Berci I think that in order for the additive structure to be one of a topological group, we need that the map the takes a vector to its negative will be continuous. The continuity of this map comes by continuity of multiplication by minus 1. Thus we must use at least some multiplicative structure of the TVS.

Comment: @Sheve additive inverses are part of the group structure